# Develop an android and iPhone application with shared database

Tags: android, iphone

I have a great idea for smartphone application, And I want to develop an application suited for both android and iPhone. In addition I need to use spatial database for geo indexing that will be shared for both applications. I am new to this app world and I have some questions.

- Is there away to develop for both machines? I know java but not objective c.

My guess is that I need to separate the database from the computing to support both applications.

- What are the best cloud computing providers with spatial database support that can host the server?
- Do I need 2 hosting servers or there is one server the can support the both of them?
- which database provider can support geo indexing and support this intergration, 
  I prefer providers with reasonable free quotas.

Comment: sorry, so for what it is related?
I thought that there is an experienced fellas here that might help me.

Comment: I think it's http://superuser.com/

Comment: StackOverflow is the good resource for questions like this, peeps. His questions about scalability might be better suited for ServerFault but the development stuff (and products suited towards developers, like Parse) can be answered here. I upvoted from -4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at www.parse.com

They have iOS and Android SDKs. All of the cloud backend is handled for you and is quite easy to implement. You'll need at least SOME Objective-C chops of course, but if you follow the guides it should be quite easy.

All of the PHP, MySQL type stuff is abstracted away, and you don't need to worry about scaling and all the other headaches that come from cloud services.